# How to deal with the error " MQRC_BUFFER_ERROR"?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

MQ application team said their application got the MQRC 2008 return code when tring to get message from queue. I google with this return code but find nothing but **MQRC_BUFFER_ERROR**. And i don't undersand the description from MQ inforcenter as below:

> **Explanation**
>
> The Buffer parameter is not valid for one of the following reasons:
>   The parameter pointer is not valid. (It is not always possible to detect parameter pointers that are not valid; if not detected, unpredictable results occur.)
>   The parameter pointer points to storage that cannot be accessed for the entire length specified by BufferLength.
>   For calls where Buffer is an output parameter: the parameter pointer points to read-only storage.

Can you help tell me how to handle this error? Or What kind of perspective am i supposed to take in order to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us code snippet that makes MQ to throw this error

Comment: The error is possibly because of incorrectly setting length of buffer when making a MQ API call. Code snippet would help in identifying the problem.

Comment: @Shashi i've already asked the app team send back the suspected code snippet. Once i get it, i'll upload here

Comment: @wing2ofsky, how's that code snippet coming along? :-) Voting to close, OP hasn't been seen here for over a year.